# Replace placeholders with corresponding env variables

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, sed, environment-variables

I have a configuration file with placeholders like this (stored in `/tmp/var` for this example)

```
ldap_bind_dn='${bind_dn}'
```

Now I'd like replace `${bind_dn}` with the the environment variable of the same name (which is set inside Docker).

```
export $bind_dn=CN=my-user,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

The expected result after processing aboves test file would be

```
ldap_bind_dn='CN=my-user,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com'
```

I tried `sed` but it doesn't replace it to the value of the env variable

```
$ sed "s#\${\(.*\)}#$\1#" /tmp/var 
bind_dn='$bind_dn'
```

Why `sed` replace with `$bind_dn` instead of the value? I'd expect that the variable is processed because I haven't escaped the `$` sign.

The expression itself works, only the substitution doesn't:

```
$ sed "s#\${\(.*\)}#test123#" /tmp/var 
bind_dn='test123'
```

The replacement is also done correctly when the target variable is hardcoded

```
$ sed "s#\${\(.*\)}#$bind_dn#" /tmp/var 
bind_dn='CN=my-user,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com'
```

But since we have a bunch of configuration variables, I'd like to automatically replace all env variables in the format `${NAME}` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but this one works in bash:

```
sed 's#\${\(.*\)}#`{echo,"$\1"}`#' /tmp/var | xargs -n1 -I{} echo echo "{}" | bash -s
```

It is a little bit tricky because you need bash execution for the variable replacement, that's why I'm piping it to `bash -s`

Answer (score 0):

While the env variable could be parsed by [executing `eval` with `mapfile`](https://superuser.com/a/519534/869595), this seems not suiteable for me because its a ini configuration file. The sections marked with brackets like `[general]` would throw errors. And I also have concerns to *just* execute the WHOLE line, which allows executing any command.

This is fixed by the following `awk`:

```
awk '{while(match($0,"[$]{[^}]*}")) {var=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH -3);gsub("[$]{"var"}",ENVIRON[var])}}1' < /tmp/var > /tmp/var
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why sed replace with $bind_dn instead of the value?

Because *sed* is not supposed to do shell parameter expansion in its pattern space. That's the job of the shell mainly.

Using GNU *sed*:

```
~>  cat /tmp/var
ldap_bind_dn='${bind_dn}'
~>  export bind_dn=CN=my-user,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
~>  sed -E 's/^\w+=.*/echo "&"/e' /tmp/var
ldap_bind_dn='CN=my-user,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com'
```

The `e` command (a GNU extension) in

```
sed -E 's/^\w+=.*/echo "&"/e'
```

executes the command that is found in pattern space and replaces the pattern space with the output. For this example, pattern space is `ldap_bind_dn='${bind_dn}'`, and is replaced with the output of `echo "ldap_bind_dn='${bind_dn}'"` (`&` references the whole matched portion of the pattern space in `echo "&"`). Since the argument of `echo` is in double quotes, it is subject to parameter expansion  when it is executed by the shell.

**Caveat**: Make sure that the file (/tmp/var in this example) comes from a trusted source. Otherwise it may contain lines like `foo='$(some_nasty_command)'`, which is executed when the *sed* command above runs.

Comment: I'm having an issue here with the shell script ie. sed not being able to find the env var? Why so? e.g. the above example results for me in 'sh: 1: bind_dn: not found'